# Add a Value to the Value in a Cell

Tags: excel

Is there any formula that could be written to add a value to the value in a cell?

For Example: cell A:1 has the value 5. Now I want to have some formula in cell A:1 to add '3' to the value in the cell. The cell's value should now be '8'.

And how about a formula across an entire column?
For Example: add '3' to the values in column B.

Any way this can be done either with some formula or script?

Thanks a lot,
Yon

Comment: With VBA it is utterly trivial (but Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service for those who don't know VBA but want to use it). Without VBA you run into circular reference problems There might be a clever hack, but if you want to increase each value in column B by 3 enter "=B1 + 3" in C1 and copy down -- then pasted the results *as values* in column B.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the solution very well explained: 
http://www.contextures.com/exceladdnumbertocells.html

Tip: google a little bit